# Jenkins Blue Ocean Save button

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I'm using Jenkins v. 2.176.1 and Blue Ocean Version 1.17.0. When I try to do a new Pipeline, the Button "Save" is not present on the top bar so I can'tsave my pipeline. Could you explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the link below. you have the version problems in plugins.
[click here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50883)